# pandas equivalent of SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=column2

Tags: python, pandas

What is the pandas equivalent of 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=column2'?

You have a dataframe, two columns with values. You want all rows where the numbers in both columns are the same. What's the code for that?

```
dataframe:
column1   column2
a        b
b        a
c        c
d        d
a        b
a        b

The result I want:
column1   column2
c        c
d        d
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df[df.col1 == df.col2]` or `df.query('col1 == col2')`

Comment: You might want to read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html

Comment: df[df.col1 == df.col2] worked perfectly, thank you. Very simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you will use something from Pandas called Masking

Basically, DataFrame[condition, on a column or the entire dataframe itself] returns a DataFrame where the condition is True.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'a':np.random.randint(0, 10, 100),
       'b':np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.a==df.b]
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed it was something very simple.